# Extract data to csv dynamically - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm still doing a script to extract data from N tables from N schema dynamically but i'm stuck when the script execute the command COPY it don't understand the value coming from the loop (mySchema / myTable).

Have you an idea, what's wrong in the script and how i can resolve the issue ? (the path is just an example, it's not the issue)

```
 DO $$
declare
mySchema text;
myTable text;
pathbackup text;

begin
   FOR mySchema IN  SELECT nspname FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace where nspname not in ('*', '*', '*', '*')
    loop
      for myTable in  select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname =   format('%L',mySchema)
        loop
          COPY mySchema.myTable  TO '/tmp/value.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
        end loop;
     end loop;
end;
$$
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks Adrian for your answer I will take a look :-)

Comment: FYI, `COPY` will only work with files the database server user can access and has permissions for per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the explanation ! It’s not a issue in my case because it’s for doing some dataset locally and with docker cp command I can extract the files from docker container to my machine